# Can we have same port in different sub domain in the same Public IP for Hosting two different App

Tags: azure, iis, networking, reporting-services, virtual-machine

I'm not a networking guy and I have this requirement and I'm not sure if this is possible or not. By the way, my requirement is I have two App that running on my Azure Virtual Machine it's SSRS and Asp Net Core running on IIS, the condition right now is my SSRS running on Port 441 and my IIS App run on port 443. So this will make the URL have to include the port when we need to access the SSRS page, then my Company says they don't like to add the port in the SSRS URL and then they suggest to add a subdomain for the SSRS and IIS and make it running on port 443. But as My Understanding, this is can only be Achieve if I have two different public IP rights which mean two Azure Virtual Machine one for the SSRS and one for the IIS because when I only have one public Address it still needs different port right for the different App. I just need to clarify Is this true? Or it can be done somehow

Comment: What is the operating system? Windows Server 2012 and above supports SNI, so multiple HTTPS services can share the same IP:443 binding.

Comment: I'm using Windows Server 2019, oh so I can do that do you have any document I can look up into here?

Comment: You might follow https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#sni-based-bindings Microsoft also has its official documents you can find on search engines.

Comment: Hi, @LexLi thanks for your answer just to be clear, if I go with this solution I need a wildcard certificate right?

Comment: ? SNI never requires wildcard certificates. You can use any valid certificates, so try it out first with self-signed ones if you like.

Comment: hi @LexLi so already try that use self-signed and add the subdomain name in my host and I can open the SSRS Portal. But the problem is my Windows Authentication is not working on that subdomain It just keeps popping out Authentication but it works properly in my localhost. Do I  need additional step to make it works?

Comment: It sounds like you are using a domain without SPN registration. When you access via localhost, it should use NTLM while Kerberos would be the first choice for sub-domain. So please set your browser to trust the domain and register SPN for that user.https://support.microsoft.com/en-ph/help/929650/how-to-use-spns-when-you-configure-web-applications-that-are-hosted-on

Answer (score 0):

An Azure Virtual Machine (VM) has one or more network interfaces (NIC) attached to it. Any NIC can have one or more static or dynamic public and private IP addresses assigned to it.

In this case, You could assign two public IP addresses to the same Azure VM. Here is the document--- [Assign multiple IP addresses to virtual machines using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-multiple-ip-addresses-portal)

[image]

If you need to add more than one NIC to virtual machine, see the steps by steps in [this blog for windows VM](http://tech-trainer.info/how-to-add-two-public-ips-to-azure-vm/) and [Linux VM](https://www.itinsights.org/Use-multiple-public-IP-addresses-in-Azure-VM/).